# Resizing WPF Grid layout of labels and textboxes

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am new to WPF and had a few questions with regards to layout approach and resizing strategies. Here is a screenshot of a of a tab I put together laid out solely with a series of nested grids:
[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Phqo.png)

The first grid is 2 rows: 1 row autosized for a dockpanel of buttons at the top, and a 1* row for the rest of the space at the bottom, which is split with another grid dividing the bottom space into 3rds.

I am happy with the way the layout looks here, but was wondering the best way to approach handling resizing. Currently, if I start sizing down from the default size seen in the screenshot, the containers all size great, but the font doesn't resize and soon becomes clipped.

I tried wrapping the middle grid in a viewbox, but because of the autosizing nature of the grids, and because there's a lot of empty space, the viewbox squishes the textboxes into near-0 width textboxes and distorts the original design into shown in the screenshot.

I then tried defining the middle grid with absolute pixel sizes and then wrapped it into a viewbox, but was dissatisfied with the results: Stretch fill quickly distorted the controls, and uniform fill leaves too much empty space.

Ideally the containers would size naturally by the defined ratios in the grids and create/reduce empty space as the window resizes and the text would scale up and down to fit in their containers

The current solution I have in mind is to do this winforms style and write an event handler on resize to calculate and set font sizes to a style I create in XAML. My questions are if there is a way to handle the font resizing more elegantly in XAML, and if there is a better way to layout the controls on the window. Below is the code for the middle grid that contains all of the label and textbox controls:

```
<Grid x:Name="JobTabMiddleGrid" Grid.Column="1">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="89*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="33*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="107*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="264*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="39*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="39*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="39*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="39*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="39*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="39*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="39*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="40*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="39*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="40*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="39*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="180*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--Labels for the top part input panel in job tab-->
    <Label Grid.ColumnSpan="4">Company</Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">Location</Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">Rig</Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">Well Name</Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">API Job No.</Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">State/Province</Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">County/Parish</Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="7" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">Country</Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="8" >Job Status</Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="9" >Job Type</Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="10">Field</Label>

    <!--Input boxes for the top part input panel in job tab-->
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">Company</TextBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">Location</TextBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">Rig</TextBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">Well Name</TextBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">API Job No.</TextBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">State/Province</TextBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">County/Parish</TextBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">Country</TextBox>
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">Field</TextBox>


    <!--Job Comments Section of input panel-->
    <Grid x:Name="JobCommentsGrid" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="3" Grid.RowSpan="3">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="31*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="88*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label FontWeight="Bold">Job Comments:</Label>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" AllowDrop="False" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalContentAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>

    <!--Canada and Custom Field Input Panel-->
    <Grid x:Name="JobTabMiddleBottomGrid" Grid.Row="11" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="103*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="62*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="103*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="62*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="102*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="61*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!--Canada Data inputs and button-->
        <Label>Section</Label>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1"></TextBox>
        <Label Grid.Column="2">Township</Label>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="3"></TextBox>
        <Label Grid.Column="4">Range</Label>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="5"></TextBox>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Padding="0">
            <DockPanel>
                <Image Source="canadaleaf.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Label>Canada Location Data</Label>
            </DockPanel>
        </Button>

        <!--Custom field labels at bottom of job input panel-->
        <Label Grid.Row="2">Shoe Depth</Label>
        <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2">Shoe Depth</Label>
        <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="4">Next CSG</Label>
        <Label Grid.Row="3">Work Order</Label>
        <Label Grid.Row="4">Contact No.</Label>

        <!--Custom field textboxes at bottom of job input panel-->
        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="5"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"/>


    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general the font staying the same size and the layout of the controls changing is what you want.  You stop font clipping by setting minimum height of the control.

What you seem to want is that the layout stays the same and the entire layout, including the fonts, scales with the window size.

The way to do this is with a render transform.  Here is a simple example...

```
<Window.RenderTransform>
    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ZoomX}" ScaleY="{Binding ZoomY}"/>
</Window.RenderTransform>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="40*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="60*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="40*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="30">Look here</Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="30">Look here</Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="30">Look here</Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="30">Look here</Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="30">Look here</Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="30">Look here</Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="30">Look here</Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="30">Look here</Label>
</Grid>
```

with code behind...

```
    public GridBench2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }
    public double ZoomX
    {
        get
        {
            return Width / 300;
        }
    }
    public double ZoomY
    {
        get
        {
            return Height / 300;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ZoomX"));
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ZoomY"));
    }
```

This is unlikely to be exactly what you want either.  If you resize the width and leave the height the same, the font will be stretched.  But these are the tools you will need to get wherever you are going.

Comment: This advice works well. I decided to set absolute widths on grid columns containing labels so all scaling will be applied to textbox width, and I set practical minimum and max heights on various grid columns and rows to prevent clipping. If I decide to do font scaling I may or may not use render transformations, but it's good reading and I'm sure I'll be using those techniques further down the line. Thank you